# Given $P(X=0)=P(X=3)=\frac18$ and $P(X=1)=P(X=2)=\frac38$, compute $P(X\geq 2)$ and $P(X>3)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Given $$X:
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 0           & 1           & 2           & 3          \\ 
> \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8}
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Calculate $P(X \geq 2)$ and $P(X > 3)$

I'm learning for an exam and I create this example task on my own, I hope it's solvable at all. Can you please tell me if my solution is correct and if not, how to do it correctly?

---

So for $P(X \geq 2)$ we can use the complementary probability

$$P(X \geq 2) = 1-P(X<2) = 1-\Big(P(X=0)+P(X=1)\Big)= 1-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$$

---

For $P(X>3)$ we have

$$P(X>3) = P(X \geq 4) = 1-P(X<4) = \\ =1-\Big(P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)\Big) = \\ = 1-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{3}{8}-\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{8} = 0$$

---

I doesn't necessarily need to make sense (maybe I created a bad task I mean) but it's very important for me to know if I solved it correct like that?

Comment: Please avoid `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}` in titles, especially when it is used for non universal notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. However, you are making a little more work for yourself than needed.

Okay, the probability of the complement is *sometimes* easier to evaluate than the probability of the event itself.   But you have to judge when that is so.   This is a case when it is slightly less easy.

$\mathsf P(X\geq 2)~{=\mathsf P(X=2)+\mathsf P(X=3) \\= \tfrac 38+\tfrac 18\\=\tfrac 12}$

$\mathsf P(X> 3) =0$ simply because all values greater than three are not within the support for $X$.

But anyway, you arrived at the correct answers by a method that was not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is right, though maybe a bit laborious.

For $P(X\ge 2)$ you could just have said $P(X\ge 2)=P(X=2 \lor X=3)=P(X=2)+P(X=3)=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$. Note both you and I used the summation rule because the events $X=2$ and $X=3$ (or similar events $X=0$ and $X=1$) are mutually exclusive.

$X\gt 3$ cannot happen, so $P(X\gt 3)=0$.